# how to create multiple textviews inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mysqli

I am trying to create a fragment and inside that i want to create multiple textviews whoose text is set from the data retreived from the database(mysql).
And also i want to have the feature "refresh" by which the textviews are updated with recent data from the database.Iam trying to do that but iam not getting enough idea how to do it as iam new to android programming.
Please help me with this. thank you in advance and any suggestions are acceptable.
i.e
 I have database of a person and i want to get his name and address from that,then in my activity i want to create a fragment that displays a name and address in separate textboxes and if address or name exceeds some length then i can press "more" to see left information

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `ListView` to populate data from the database, and a `SwiperRefreshLayout` to refresh it. Check these links for more info :

[SwipeRefreshLayout](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/)

[ListViews](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what your app will do.

If you have a fixed number of TextViews, and the number won't change in the future or depending on the answer to the database query, you could simply stick to normal TextViews; if the number changes, I suggest using ListViews or ExpandableListViews.

Regarding the layout, you can create a normal layout using AndroidStudio's layout designer, and then inflate it to your view.

For the refresh, you can add a button that calls the method in which you fill the textviews/listviews.

Actually your question is too broad: if you want a more specific answer, you should edit it asking what you really need.